# converting time from BST to American timeZones CST MST EST PST

Tags: java, liferay

I am converting time from GMT to different USA time-zones. For that, I have written a method which is returning the 1-hour prior time. if the time is 2:00 clock it's returning 1:00 clock

```
private static Date timeFormat(String timeZone) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    DateFormat gmtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    gmtFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault().getID()));
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = gmtFormat.parse(sdfDate.format(new Date()));
        LOG.info("GMT format time and date ==>> "+date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    DateFormat pstFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    pstFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));
    String timedd = pstFormat.format(date);
    LOG.info("Return the new time based on timezone : "+pstFormat.format(date));
    return gmtFormat.parse(timedd);
}
```

Can anybody help me out what exactly is the issue, because a few months back the same method was working fine? Is it happening because of daylight saving time?

Comment: It's very unclear what you're actually trying to do. Are you trying to get the *current* date/time in a particular time zone? It sounds like you need to read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/ - a `java.util.Date` doesn't *have* a time zone (or format).

Comment: @JonSkeet , I am converting GMT time into different US timeZones. The same time is in sync with [CST](https://time.is/CST) & [PST](https://time.is/PST) but giving different time for [EST](https://time.is/EST) & [MST](https://time.is/MST)

Comment: If you were "converting" that would require input in GMT. You don't have any such input. Furthermore, your method returns a `Date` - and a `Date` doesn't have a time zone. Please read the blog post I referred to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so much of digging i have found that TimeZone won't give correct result on basis of time-zone

> (EST, CST, MST, PST)

so in my method the param which i have passed as timeZone was coming as a

> (EST, CST, MST, PST)

Instead of `EST, CST, MST, PST` i have passed `US/Eastern` `US/Pacific` `US/Mountain` `US/Central`, and it worked fine for me

Comment: Actually, [real time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) are in a format of `Continent/Region` such as `America/Chicago`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a much simpler way using java.time APIs. Use Instant to represent the time in UTC. It can be converted to time at any zone, and formatted to a particular pattern.

```
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Instant now = Instant.now();
ZonedDateTime dt = now.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC-05:00"));
System.out.println(dt.format(format)); //2017-05-24 04:51:03
ZonedDateTime pstDate = now.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC-07:00"));
System.out.println(pstDate.format(format)); //2017-05-24 02:51:03
```

Comment: Getting `Prohibited package name: java.time.format`

Comment: Are you on JDK8 ? java.time package was introduced in JDK8

Comment: I am using JDK7

Comment: Most of the java.time functionality is backported to JDK 7 with http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/ , its worth utilizing this rather than using cumbersome legacy Date functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

Use modern *java.time* classes, not the terribly flawed legacy classes.

> new Date()));

No, capture the current moment using `Instant` class. This class represents a moment as seen with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

> from GMT

In the realm of most business apps, GMT is equivalent to UTC.

For science and engineering, there is a difference. Irrelevant to most of us.

> to different USA time-zones

There are many time zones across the US and its territories.

Real time zones have a name in format of `Continent/Region` such as `America/Chicago`, `America/Juneau`, `America/Kentucky/Louisville`, `America/Los_Angeles`, `Pacific/Guam`.

So you will need to be more specific.

```
List < ZoneId > zoneIds =
    List.of(
        ZoneId.of( "America/Juneau" ) ,
        ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" ) ,
        ZoneId.of( "America/Chicago" ) ,
        ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) 
    )
;
for ( ZoneId zoneId : zoneIds ) 
{
    ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( zoneId ) ;
    String output = zdt.toString() ;  // Standard ISO 8601 format, wisely extended by appending the name of the time zone in square brackets.
    System.out.println( output ) ;
}
```

See this code [run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/ItNg11).

```
2023-03-27T04:23:55.441822Z
2023-03-26T20:23:55.441822-08:00[America/Juneau]
2023-03-26T21:23:55.441822-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]
2023-03-26T23:23:55.441822-05:00[America/Chicago]
2023-03-27T00:23:55.441822-04:00[America/New_York]
```

You commented:

> CST & PST but giving different time for EST & MST

Such 2-4 character pseudo-zones are not real time zone names. They are not standardized. They are not unique. Use real time zone names as seen above.